# Why does changing a duped object alter the original?

Tags: ruby, class, reference, dup

I came across this problem and I need some help understanding why the original object was also changed; I was under the impression that ".dup" will create a new object for the pointer to reference, is this wrong?

```
class Pawn
  attr_accessor :position

  def initialize(position)
    @position = position
  end
end

pawn = Pawn.new([0, 1])
pawn_copy = pawn.dup

pawn_copy.position[1] = "CHANGED"
pawn.position #=> the result is [0, "CHANGED"]
```

Comment: What language is the upper part?

Comment: This is Ruby, not Python. `dup` creates a shallow copy, it won't duplicate the inner objects (such as `position`). In this case `pawn_copy = Pawn.new(pawn.position.dup)` may work (not tested).

Comment: @Karen : For creating a deep copy, do a `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(pawn))` instead of `pawn.dup`.

Comment: Short answer: Because you didn't modify `pawn_copy` at all. You modified the array stored under the *position* attribute. Both `pawn` and `pawn_copy` hold a reference to this same array.

Comment: Add a `initialize_copy` method to your class (`def initialize_copy(orig); @position = @position.dup; end`. The `pawn.dup` works.